# How to add custom field in yii

Tags: yii, yii-extensions, yii-components

How to add field dynamically in yii, is it possible to field show dynamically in each category,I want to show

field dynamic for each category and also how to get details of the field and save in db.Please help me to add dymanic add field and get details.

Please tell is it possible in yii..

For Example:If i choose Category Cars & Bikes > Motorcycles Mean it show field Kms Driven,Brand Name etc related to bike catgory suppose i choose Apartment category mean it show No. of Rooms,Area Sq Ft related to apartment wise.

Comment: Are all the field in a single table, or do you have different tables for category, cars and bikes, apartment, etc.

Comment: You can create a custom attribute at database and store in there an array or a serialized object, you can save a different object/array according to the category. Want extra info?